# Jenkins 2.46.2 : Active Directory domain name is required but it is not set

Tags: jenkins, active-directory, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins 2.46.2 has an issue with Active Directory. When deployed the Jenkins.war file under Tomcat webapps after, i see the below error when accessing Jenkins. This is a brand new Jenkins site and i did no even install any plugins yet. Is there anything that i am missing ?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'activeDirectory' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'activeDirectory': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Active Directory domain name is required but it is not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at hudson.util.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:94)
    at hudson.util.spring.BeanBuilder.createApplicationContext(BeanBuilder.java:391)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.createSecurityComponents(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:187)
    at hudson.security.SecurityRealm.getSecurityComponents(SecurityRealm.java:455)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.reset(HudsonFilter.java:138)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.setSecurityRealm(Jenkins.java:2553)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$19.run(Jenkins.java:3149)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:1089)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You might have to install active directory plugin and configure. Please provide a bit more info

Comment: This is even before installing plugins. I have just copied the Jenkins.war file to tomcat and then in the browser I see this error message

Comment: Can you see anything in the logs. If you cant find them, start jenkins from the commandline and post what you see in the console

Comment: I had to cleanup the old Jenkins folder and restart Tomcat. After that it started working.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a old jenkins folder and any cache left behind has to be cleaned before upgrading to new jenkins.